# How do I use FileOpen (VB.NET) in C#? How do I convert this code?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

So, I'm working on converting this code from VB.NET to C#:

```
FileOpen(1, Application.StartupPath & "\Stub.exe", _
    OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
```

I've used a series of online converters, and they don't really work for me.

How do I do it? I'm trying to understand VB.NET source code so I can use it in.

Comment: what is this code suppose to do. i.e run Stub.exe application or open a file stream from the Stub.exe file

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code.

```
BinaryReader br =
    new BinaryReader(
        new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "/stub.exe",
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.Read));
```

Comment: Note BinaryReader implements IDisposable and should be wrapped in a using statement.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx). There are C# examples provided.

Comment: That's `System.IO.File.Open`, not `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileOpen` which is provided for backward compatibility with VB6 code.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to redevelop the code using a `BinaryReader`.

If there's a lot of code and you are pressed for time, you could import `Microsoft.VisualBasic` into your C# project and then use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileOpen`.